# Google Maps api key - cross platform

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a working **iOS** app which uses **Google Maps API** and makes api calls directly from the app. Now I am moving some logic to backend services in **Node.js**. I want to get data from maps api, and send it back to the app for presentation.

Also google intro video tells me I should route all my api requests to a web server and then web server should send the request to **Google Maps API**. 
My confusion is if I am using web service, why would I need a **iOS** key at all except for displaying the map itself?

What is the best or standard practice here? Need architecture/design advice here.

App is basically getting various pieces together directions, places etc and displaying them on map. I plan to build a native android app as well with same functionality.

Comment: you can create key without adding any sha1 key in console

Comment: Please be more specific on your question topic, it's very broad, try to write (in short) what doesn't work or what you wanna know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Following Google's instructions (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key), you should create an API key for each different platform you're developing for.

In this case, I would recommend you create an API key for your iOS app, a server key for your web service, and another client API key for your future Android app (different than the iOS one).

When you go to your Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and ask to create a new API key, you can see that Google gives you different choices: server key, browser key, iOS key, Android key, etc. Each different key serves different purposes and should be limited to the corresponding platform only (e.g.: do not put a server key in a client app like an iOS app, and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

For this part of your question..."Also google intro video tells me i should route all my api requests to a web server and then web server should send the request to google maps. My confusion is if I am using web service, why would I need a iOS key at all except for displaying the map itself"

I think what they are talking about is your javascript file for example should be on a webserver. Without knowing exactly what you are referring I can't say but that can be a confusing statement by them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. I am looking for best practice flow.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. I am looking for best practice flow. Call flow should be app--> web server --> maps api or app--> maps api and app--> web server . I want to save parts of the data returned by maps api to mongo db. So I can technically do it both ways. 1) app to maps api, then once user is done i can save the changes to my mongo server, 2) app to web server --> maps api. Then web server saves the data to mongo before returning to app. Second approach saves me trip to web server. This what I am trying to decide option 1 or 2. and what is a typical practice for such scenarios.